# Cannot connect to FoxPro database due to architecture mismatch between Driver and Application

Tags: odbc, 64-bit, visual-studio-2005, foxpro, dsn

Getting this error message when attempting to connect to a FoxPro database via a DSN on a Windows 7 x64 PC:

> The specified DSN contains an architecture mismatch between the Driver and Application

This project uses Visual Studio 2005.  The connection settings point to a 32-bit DSN ODBC configuration correctly.  Not using the default x64 ODBC DSN.  I even went into the registry (Wow6432Node) to make sure the FoxPro driver was pointing to the driver in the 32-bit location (sysWow64 directory).

Stumped - any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The Visual Studio 2005 project was configured for "Any CPU", and needed to be set to x86 explicitly.  That was the difference, even though the DSN was pointing to the correct 32-bit driver.

Platform target: x86